# bcrypt-3.1.11 error when runing bundle install

Tags: ruby, bcrypt

I was working on a file today and all of a sudden when bundling I get an error about bcrypt 3.1.11 . I have scoured the internet as to how to solve this.

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies.................................
Using rake 11.3.0
/Users/linc/.gem/ruby/2.2.3/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:289: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/sbin in PATH, mode 040777
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.9.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
Using pkg-config 1.1.7
Using rack 1.6.4
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using arel 6.0.3
Using addressable 2.4.0
Installing bcrypt 3.1.11 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/linc/.rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160927-27635-1pd08jr.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling bcrypt_ext.c
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
clang: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.clang: note: diagnostic msg:
********************
PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/0v/x6vrj7v12hd5bghty3yqt7sr0000gn/T/bcrypt_ext-b63617.c
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/0v/x6vrj7v12hd5bghty3yqt7sr0000gn/T/bcrypt_ext-b63617.sh
clang: note: diagnostic msg:
********************
make: *** [bcrypt_ext.o] Error 254

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/linc/.gem/ruby/2.2.3/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/linc/.gem/ruby/2.2.3/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/bcrypt-3.1.11/gem_make.out
Using bundler 1.11.2
Using coderay 1.1.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
Using docile 1.1.5
Using simplecov-html 0.10.0
Using tins 1.12.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using diff-lcs 1.2.5
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using sass 3.4.22
Using method_source 0.8.2
Using pg 0.19.0
Using slop 3.6.0
Using puma 3.6.0
Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
Using rspec-support 3.5.0
Using tilt 2.0.5
Using shoulda-context 1.2.1
Using valid_attribute 2.0.0
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.8
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using warden 1.2.6
Using mime-types 3.1
Using launchy 2.4.3
An error occurred while installing bcrypt (3.1.11), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.11' succeeds before bundling.
```

I have done the `xcode-select --install` and `bundle installed` and still get the same error.
I have `gem uninstall bcrypt "3.1.11"` and `gem installed bcrypt "3.1.11"` again and still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Restarted computer and it began working again. Very weird bug